# How can I restrict the generation of permutations? (In Java)

Tags: java, algorithm

```
Dataset:
P1: Lion, Snow, Chair
P2: Min: 0, Max: 28
P3: Min: 34, Max is 39.
```

**My Program** is fed the above dataset (P1, P2, P3) as a series of arraylists. From this it continuously outputs different variations of a sequence including one element from each part (P1, P2, P3), until all possible permutations have been generated. (When generated P2 and P3 can be any number between their respective Min and Max.)

**Examples of these sequences:**

```
[Lion, 2, 37]
[Lion, 3, 34]
[Lion, 3, 35]
[Chair, 15, 35]
[Chair, 15, 36]
[Chair, 15, 37]
[Snow, 25, 36]
[Snow, 25, 37]
[Snow, 26, 34]
```

**How?**

- To achieve this, I make use of the getCombinations function with P1,
  P2 and P3 as parameters.  To prepare the P2 and P3 arraylists for
  use, I make use of the fillArrayList function which iterates from a
  min to a max filling and then returning the relevant arraylist.
- The problem I am facing is, I'm confused (lost) as to how I restrict the output of permutations which can lead to a 'Bad outcome' as below:

**e.g.**

- P1 = Lion && P2 > 23 && P3 <= 35 Then Bad Outcome.
- P1 = Lion && P2 < 13 && P3 >= 37 Then Bad Outcome.
- P1 = Chair && P2 < 7 && P3 = 34 Then Bad Outcome.

Although I would be content to statically encoding a series of conditional statements for each, as these steps are read from a file which can change, this approach isn't applicable.

**Code:**

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataset = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> rows = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    static ArrayList<String> NegativePredictions = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        init();

        for (ArrayList<String> curArrayList : dataset) {
            ArrayList<String> currentRule = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (curArrayList.size() > 2) {
                currentRule = curArrayList;

            } else {
                currentRule = new ArrayList<String>(
                        fillArrayList(Integer.parseInt(curArrayList.get(0)), Integer.parseInt(curArrayList.get(1))));

            }

            rows.add(currentRule);
        }
        getCombinations(rows).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static void init() throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> P1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Lion", "Snow", "Chair"));
        ArrayList<String> P2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("0", "28"));
        ArrayList<String> P3 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("34", "37"));

        dataset = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(Arrays.asList(P1, P2, P3));

        NegativePredictions = new ArrayList<String>(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Predict.txt")));

    }

    public static ArrayList<String> fillArrayList(Integer start, Integer end) {

        ArrayList<String> returnedList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            returnedList.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        return returnedList;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> List<List<T>> getCombinations(Collection<? extends Iterable<T>> valueSetCollection) {
        Iterable<T>[] valueSets = new Iterable[valueSetCollection.size()];
        Iterator<T>[] valueIters = new Iterator[valueSetCollection.size()];
        T[] values = (T[]) new Object[valueSetCollection.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Iterable<T> valueSet : valueSetCollection) {
            valueSets[i] = valueSet; // Copy to array for fast index lookup
            valueIters[i] = valueSet.iterator();
            values[i] = valueIters[i].next(); // Fail if a wordSet is empty
            i++;
        }
        List<List<T>> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
        NEXT_COMBO: for (;;) {
            combinations.add(Arrays.asList(values.clone()));
            for (i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (valueIters[i].hasNext()) {
                    values[i] = valueIters[i].next();
                    continue NEXT_COMBO;
                }
                valueIters[i] = valueSets[i].iterator();
                values[i] = valueIters[i].next();
            }
            return combinations;
        }
    }
}
```

**What would you recommend?**

Comment: in what way can the file change and in what way would your conditions have to respond? Can you give some examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider encoding a rule, where a set of rules determines if that particular candidate permutation is included or excluded.  For example, an interface to define a rule:

```
    public interface ExclusionRule<X> {
        public boolean isExcluded(X x);
    }
```

along with several implementations which know how to make comparisons with a String or an Integer:

```
    public class ExcludeIfEqualStringRule implements ExclusionRule<String> {
        private final String exclusion;

        public ExcludeIfEqualStringRule(String exclusion) {
            this.exclusion = exclusion;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isExcluded(String x) {
            return x.equals(exclusion);
        }
    }

    public abstract class AbstractExcludeIntegerRule implements ExclusionRule<Integer> {
        private final int threshold;
        private final ExclusionRule<Integer> or;

        public AbstractExcludeIntegerRule(int threshold, ExclusionRule<Integer> or) {
            this.threshold = threshold;
            this.or = or;
        }

        @Override
        public final boolean isExcluded(Integer x) {
            if (or != null) {
                return or.isExcluded(x) || doComparison(x, threshold);
            }

            return doComparison(x, threshold);
        }

        protected abstract boolean doComparison(int x, int threshold);
    }

    public class ExcludeIfGreaterThanIntegerRule extends AbstractExcludeIntegerRule {

        public ExcludeIfGreaterThanIntegerRule(int threshold, ExclusionRule<Integer> or) {
            super(threshold, or);
        }

        public ExcludeIfGreaterThanIntegerRule(int threshold) {
            this(threshold, null);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean doComparison(int x, int threshold) {
            return x > threshold;
        }
    }

    public class ExcludeIfLessThanIntegerRule extends AbstractExcludeIntegerRule {

        public ExcludeIfLessThanIntegerRule(int threshold, ExclusionRule<Integer> or) {
            super(threshold, or);
        }

        public ExcludeIfLessThanIntegerRule(int threshold) {
            this(threshold, null);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean doComparison(int x, int threshold) {
            return x < threshold;
        }
    }

    public class ExcludeIfEqualIntegerRule extends AbstractExcludeIntegerRule {

        public ExcludeIfEqualIntegerRule(int threshold, ExclusionRule<Integer> or) {
            super(threshold, or);
        }

        public ExcludeIfEqualIntegerRule(int threshold) {
            this(threshold, null);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean doComparison(int x, int threshold) {
            return x == threshold;
        }
    }
```

Along with another class which defines the set of rules to evaluate any candidate permutation:

```
    public class ExclusionEvaluator<T, U, V> {
        private final ExclusionRule<T> tRule;
        private final ExclusionRule<U> uRule;
        private final ExclusionRule<V> vRule;

        public ExclusionEvaluator(ExclusionRule<T> tRule, ExclusionRule<U> uRule, ExclusionRule<V> vRule) {
            this.tRule = tRule;
            this.uRule = uRule;
            this.vRule = vRule;
        }

        public boolean isExcluded(T t, U u, V v) {
            return tRule.isExcluded(t) && uRule.isExcluded(u) && vRule.isExcluded(v);
        }
    }
```

With the three lists as separate objects, this can be encapsulated within another class which provides the `getCombinations()`  method:

```
    public class PermutationProvider<T, U, V> {
        private final List<T> tItems;
        private final List<U> uItems;
        private final List<V> vItems;
        private final List<ExclusionEvaluator<T, U, V>> exclusionEvaluators;

        public PermutationProvider(List<T> tItems, List<U> uItems, List<V> vItems, List<ExclusionEvaluator<T, U, V>> exclusionEvaluators) {
            this.tItems = tItems;
            this.uItems = uItems;
            this.vItems = vItems;
            this.exclusionEvaluators = exclusionEvaluators;
        }

        public List<Permutation<T, U, V>> getCombinations() {
            List<Permutation<T, U, V>> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
            for (T tElement : tItems) {
                for (U uElement : uItems) {
                    for (V vElement : vItems) {
                        Permutation<T, U, V> p = new Permutation<>(tElement, uElement, vElement);
                        if (isExcluded(tElement, uElement, vElement)) {
                            System.out.println(p + " IS EXCLUDED");
                        } else {
                            combinations.add(p);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return combinations;
        }

        private boolean isExcluded(T tElement, U uElement, V vElement) {
            for (ExclusionEvaluator<T, U, V> exclusionEvaluator : exclusionEvaluators) {
                if (exclusionEvaluator.isExcluded(tElement, uElement, vElement)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

and result class to hold a permutation:

```
    public class Permutation<T, U, V> {
        private final T t;
        private final U u;
        private final V v;

        public Permutation(T t, U u, V v) {
            this.t = t;
            this.u = u;
            this.v = v;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return t.toString() + " " + u.toString() + " " + v.toString();
        }
    }
```

along with a driver class to build the lists, exclusion rules, and get the accepted permutations:

```
public class PermuteWithExclusionsApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PermuteWithExclusionsApp().permute();
    }

    private void permute() {
        List<String> p1 = Arrays.asList("Lion", "Chair", "Snow");

        List<Integer> p2 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 28; i++) {
            p2.add(i);
        }

        List<Integer> p3 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 34; i <= 39; i++) {
            p3.add(i);
        }

        // read from a file or some other source
        List<String> compoundExclusionRules = Arrays.asList("P1 = Lion && P2 > 23 && P3 <= 35", "P1 = Lion && P2 < 13 && P3 >= 37", "P1 = Chair && P2 < 7 && P3 = 34");

        ExclusionRuleFactory<String> stringRuleFactory = new StringExclusionRuleFactory();
        ExclusionRuleFactory<Integer> integerRuleFactory = new IntegerExclusionRuleFactory();
        ExclusionEvaluatorFactory<String, Integer, Integer> evaluatorFactory = new ExclusionEvaluatorFactory<>(stringRuleFactory, integerRuleFactory, integerRuleFactory);

        List<ExclusionEvaluator<String, Integer, Integer>> evaluators = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String compoundExclusionRule : compoundExclusionRules) {
            evaluators.add(evaluatorFactory.create(compoundExclusionRule));
        }

        //      List<ExclusionEvaluator<String, Integer, Integer>> evaluators = new ArrayList<>();
        //      evaluators.add(getExclusionRul1());
        //      evaluators.add(getExclusionRul2());
        //      evaluators.add(getExclusionRul3());

        PermutationProvider<String, Integer, Integer> provider = new PermutationProvider<>(p1, p2, p3, evaluators);
        List<Permutation<String, Integer, Integer>> permuations = provider.getCombinations();
        for (Permutation<String, Integer, Integer> p : permuations) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }

    //  private ExclusionEvaluator<String, Integer, Integer> getExclusionRul3() {
    //      ExclusionRule<String> p1Rule = new ExcludeIfEqualStringRule("Chair");
    //      ExclusionRule<Integer> p2Rule = new ExcludeIfLessThanIntegerRule(7);
    //      ExclusionRule<Integer> p3Rule = new ExcludeIfEqualIntegerRule(34);
    //      return new ExclusionEvaluator<String, Integer, Integer>(p1Rule, p2Rule, p3Rule);
    //  }
    //
    //  private ExclusionEvaluator<String, Integer, Integer> getExclusionRul2() {
    //      ExclusionRule<String> p1Rule = new ExcludeIfEqualStringRule("Lion");
    //      ExclusionRule<Integer> p2Rule = new ExcludeIfLessThanIntegerRule(13);
    //      ExclusionRule<Integer> p3Rule = new ExcludeIfGreaterThanIntegerRule(37, new ExcludeIfEqualIntegerRule(37));
    //      return new ExclusionEvaluator<String, Integer, Integer>(p1Rule, p2Rule, p3Rule);
    //  }
    //
    //  private ExclusionEvaluator<String, Integer, Integer> getExclusionRul1() {
    //      ExclusionRule<String> p1Rule = new ExcludeIfEqualStringRule("Lion");
    //      ExclusionRule<Integer> p2Rule = new ExcludeIfGreaterThanIntegerRule(23);
    //      ExclusionRule<Integer> p3Rule = new ExcludeIfLessThanIntegerRule(35, new ExcludeIfEqualIntegerRule(35));
    //      return new ExclusionEvaluator<String, Integer, Integer>(p1Rule, p2Rule, p3Rule);
    //  }
```

Here's an example of a factory to parse the exclusion rules if for example the rules were defined as text.

```
    public interface ExclusionRuleFactory<Z> {
        public ExclusionRule<Z> create(String operator, String operand);
    }

    public class StringExclusionRuleFactory implements ExclusionRuleFactory<String> {

        @Override
        public ExclusionRule<String> create(String operator, String operand) {
            return new ExcludeIfEqualStringRule(operand);
        }
    }

    public class IntegerExclusionRuleFactory implements ExclusionRuleFactory<Integer> {

        @Override
        public ExclusionRule<Integer> create(String operator, String operand) {
            int threshold = Integer.parseInt(operand);

            switch (operator) {
            case "=":
                return new ExcludeIfEqualIntegerRule(threshold);

            case ">":
                return new ExcludeIfGreaterThanIntegerRule(threshold);

            case "<":
                return new ExcludeIfLessThanIntegerRule(threshold);

            case ">=":
                return new ExcludeIfGreaterThanIntegerRule(threshold, new ExcludeIfEqualIntegerRule(threshold));

            case "<=":
                return new ExcludeIfLessThanIntegerRule(threshold, new ExcludeIfEqualIntegerRule(threshold));
            }

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported operator " + operator);
        }
    }

    public class ExclusionEvaluatorFactory<T, U, V> {
        private final ExclusionRuleFactory<T> p1RuleFactory;
        private final ExclusionRuleFactory<U> p2RuleFactory;
        private final ExclusionRuleFactory<V> p3RuleFactory;

        public ExclusionEvaluatorFactory(ExclusionRuleFactory<T> p1RuleFactory, ExclusionRuleFactory<U> p2RuleFactory, ExclusionRuleFactory<V> p3RuleFactory) {
            this.p1RuleFactory = p1RuleFactory;
            this.p2RuleFactory = p2RuleFactory;
            this.p3RuleFactory = p3RuleFactory;
        }

        public ExclusionEvaluator<T, U, V> create(String compoundExclusionRule) {
            ExclusionRule<T> p1Rule = null;
            ExclusionRule<U> p2Rule = null;
            ExclusionRule<V> p3Rule = null;

            String[] exclusionSubRules = compoundExclusionRule.split("&&");
            for (int sr = 0; sr < exclusionSubRules.length; sr++) {

                String[] ruleParts = exclusionSubRules[sr].trim().split(" ");
                String whichRule = ruleParts[0].trim(); 
                String operator = ruleParts[1].trim();
                String operand = ruleParts[2].trim();

                switch (whichRule) {
                case "P1":
                    p1Rule = p1RuleFactory.create(operator, operand);
                    break;

                case "P2":
                    p2Rule = p2RuleFactory.create(operator, operand);
                    break;

                case "P3":
                    p3Rule = p3RuleFactory.create(operator, operand);
                    break;
                }
            }

            return new ExclusionEvaluator<T, U, V>(p1Rule, p2Rule, p3Rule);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean *but they could be moved to a Factory*?

Comment: Suppose each line of a rules file has text similar to "P1 = Lion && P2 > 23 && P3 <= 35". Each of those Strings could be a parameter to an `ExclusionEvaluatorFactory` class, where the factory parses the String and returns an appropriate `ExclusionEvaluator` instance.

Comment: Could you provide an example? Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer and added a factory to parse the exclusion rules.

Comment: How would you modify the  *ExclusionEvaluator* class to allow for rule lines which may not mention all parts, or may mention a given part more than once for example "P1 = Lion && P2 > 23 && P2 <= 35"?

Comment: Change `ExclusionEvaluator` to use Lists, e.g. `public ExclusionEvaluator(List<ExclusionRule<T>> tRule, List<ExclusionRule<U>> uRule, List<ExclusionRule<V>> vRule)`, and an empty, non-null List indicates that part was not mentioned in the rule.

Comment: [When I try](http://i64.tinypic.com/wbp94m.jpg), I get the error *The method isExcluded(List<ExclusionRule<V>>) is undefined for the type List<ExclusionRule<V>>*

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: The interface would also need to be updated to accept a `List<V>` instead of just a `V`.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a `Predicate` function to your `getCombinations` method to filter or accept certain combinations:

```
/** Returns true if this combination is accepted, false if it should be filtered. */
public static boolean myFilter(Object[] combo) {
    // Object arrays and casting is gross
    if (combo.length != 3) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        String p1 = (String) combo[0];
        // Why are they strings?
        Integer p2 = Integer.valueOf((String) combo[1]);
        Integer p3 = Integer.valueOf((String) combo[2]);

        return !("Lion".equals(p1) && (13 > p2) && (35 >= p3))
                && !("Lion".equals(p1) && (13 > p2) && (37 <= p3))
                && !("Chair".equals(p1) && (7 > p2) && (34 == p3));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // invalid combination, filter it
        return false;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> List<List<T>> getCombinations(
        Collection<? extends Iterable<T>> valueSetCollection,
        Predicate<Object[]> filter) {
    Iterable<T>[] valueSets = new Iterable[valueSetCollection.size()];
    Iterator<T>[] valueIters = new Iterator[valueSetCollection.size()];
    T[] values = (T[]) new Object[valueSetCollection.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Iterable<T> valueSet : valueSetCollection) {
        valueSets[i] = valueSet; // Copy to array for fast index lookup
        valueIters[i] = valueSet.iterator();
        values[i] = valueIters[i].next(); // Fail if a wordSet is empty
        i++;
    }
    List<List<T>> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
    NEXT_COMBO: for (;;) {
        T[] v = values.clone();
        if (filter.test(v)) {
            combinations.add(Arrays.asList(v));
        } else {
            System.out.println("rejected " + Arrays.asList(v));
        }
        for (i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (valueIters[i].hasNext()) {
                values[i] = valueIters[i].next();
                continue NEXT_COMBO;
            }
            valueIters[i] = valueSets[i].iterator();
            values[i] = valueIters[i].next();
        }
        return combinations;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    // ...
    getCombinations(rows, MyClass::myFilter).forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("##############################");
    // accept all
    getCombinations(rows, o -> true).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

---

Also, rather than passing lists of lists it may be better to make a data container class like this:

```
public class MyCombination {
    private final String s;
    private final int i1;
    private final int i2;
    public MyCombination(String s, int i1, int i2){
        this.s = s;
        this.i1 = i1;
        this.i2 = i2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, you've encoded the conditional statements statically within the *myFilter* method. But I state within my question, that this approach isn't applicable *as these steps are read from a file which can change*.